# check if textfield contain A-Z and &

Tags: php, regex

How to check if a string only contains a-z, A-Z or & sign?

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]+&/', $sender_t))
{
    echo 'good';
}
else { echo 'no good'; }
```

Comment: Why not put the ampersand (`&`) inside the square brackets?

Comment: What is the current problem with the code? Is there an error or a certain case that it does not match?

Comment: & inside the bracket solve what he needs

Comment: so if my string contains anything else other than a-z, A-Z, & it's no good

Comment: You're checking that the string doesn't (`!preg_match`) contains at least one character that **isn't** (the `^`) `A-Z` or`a-z`, followed by an ampersand. I'm guessing what you're after is `/[A-Za-z&]+/` and skip the negation (`!`) in the test of `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

```
$sender_t = '&&';
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z&]/', $sender_t))
{
   echo 'good';
}
else 
{ 
   echo 'no good'; 
}
```

Comment: I get echo as good, I am running it here - https://repl.it/languages/php

Comment: it's work! I used htmlspecialchars - that's why it was not worked

Comment: aah ... got it... for once I thought, I made a mistake and would be soon getting a downvote from you.. :p

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z&]+$/', $sender_t))
{
    echo 'good';
}
else { echo 'no good'; }
```

Note that the circumflex `^` is outside the character class `[...]`, to match *beginning of line* (**not** inside, to negate the character class), and the added `$` at the end to match *end of line*.

It'll match when sender contains only english letters or ampersands (at least one).